# Lechucks Fortress Acid Pit Bug

Tags: monkey-island-2-lechucks-revenge-se

I have recently started playing *Monkey Island 2: Special Edition* on Steam and have finally gotten to LeChuck's Fortress and have been hovering over the acid pit.

After some length of mindless messing about I fell into the acid and died so after a short cutscene with Elaine I am returned to hovering over the acid pit, this time with no cursor and no way of doing anything except bringing up the menu or changing to "old school" graphics mode.  No inventory, no way to interact with anything, nada.

My problem is that in exiting the game it saved over the autosave and now I have no way to go back even a few minutes.

This is 75% into the game and I really don't want to have to play through the entire thing just to get back to this point.

I've found a [couple of threads on the Steam forums that seem to indicate that LucasArts consider this a "will not fix" bug](https://web.archive.org/web/20170521190642/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1350583).

Does anyone know of a way around this or where I can find a saved game just after (or just before) this point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Triggered by Alex I had another look around and on the [thread I linked in my question](https://web.archive.org/web/20170521190642/http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1350583) some kindly soul had posted a link to a 4shared file which had a nice comprehensive saved game with saves at all the major points in the game.  I now have a save that appears to be moments before this bug occurs.

For those who may come across this in the future the file is at http://www.4shared.com/file/p3so33m4/MI2SEsaves.html

Simply open the archive and extract the "32460" directory in its entirety to your `Steam\userdata\%STEAMID%\` directory.  Backup your current `32460` directory if you like, though I'd consider it optional as the "dead" save is pretty much useless.

Comment: URL no longer contains the files.

Answer (score 2):

An update was released in July which *probably* fixed this: [TalesOfMI.net article](http://talesofmi.net/?p=1082)

It's not explicitly mentioned as the acid pit bug but they mention addressing certain 'cursor issues'. Some of the comments on that page indicate that it was indeed fixed with this patch.

If you happen to test it and can confirm either way, let me know and I'll update this answer.

Comment: Sadly that update was July of last year (2010), quite a while before I started my playthrough.  There's even someone else who states that the game is pretty much dead due to the bug (http://talesofmi.net/?p=1082&cpage=1#comment-220211) and that's pretty much how I've left it.  I can't play past that point and can't be bothered to re-play to get back up to the point as I've games with less show-stopping bugs to play...  Thanks for the answer though, it was interesting that there was at least *some* updates on the game.

Comment: Still happening in 2021